# How to convert CSV to JSON with value in double quotes using com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper in Java?

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml, dataformat

Suppose CSV data is like below:

SiteName,Location, Recurrence Type, Time Zone
TestSite_QA2_0401,QA_LocationAZ_0401,"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE",Europe/Paris

*Expected JSON:*

SiteName=TestSite_QA2_0401, Location=QA_LocationAZ_0401, Recurrence Type="FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE", Time Zone=Europe/Paris

*Actual result getting using below logic:*

SiteName=TestSite_QA2_0401, Location=QA_LocationAZ_0401, Recurrence Type=FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE, Time Zone=Europe/Paris

I'm mapping this CSV data to JSON using below logic:

CsvSchema bootstrap = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
return csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(bootstrap).readValues(input).readAll();

Any suggestion/help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you serialize the data to JSON.

Comment: `"` is part of `csv` format, not part of value.

Comment: @Henry parsing csv to json using csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(bootstrap).readValues(input).readAll()

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.withQuoteChar((char) 0).withEscapeChar((char) 0)`.

It will turn of quoting and escaping.

**Strongly suggest you not to do it**

Comment: I have tried with this, but getting an exception :

com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMappingException: Too many entries: expected at most 4 (value #4 (2 chars) "TU")
 at [Source: (com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.UTF8Reader)